# Relative frequency question

Tags: self-study, histogram, frequency

I am a new user here, and I need some help getting started with the following question:

[image]

The textbook answers are a. $19$ and b. $20$. How do I begin this question? I am a beginner in statistics. :)

Is the reason the answer is $19$ because $\frac{2}{20}+\frac{1}{20}=0.15$? and the answer is $20$ because $\frac{1}{20}=0.05$?

Comment: Please adding a self-study tag, after reading it's info page: https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Comment: Well, try making the relative frequency histogram, and see how often you would have run out of stock having 17,18,19,... items at the beginning of the week.

Comment: The sorted observation are:  `9 12 13 14 14 15 15 15 15 15 15 16 16 16 17 18 18 19 19 20` and according to R the 85th and 95th percentiles are 18.15 and 19.05, respectively. If you have 19 in stock that might take care of 85% of weeks but not 95%; if you have 20 in stock that might take care of 95% of weeks. I say 'might' because you do not have nearly enough data to predict confidently.